# Catalyst support for Firebase MLNLTranslate

Tags: firebase, firebase-mlkit, mac-catalyst

I want to build a iPad/Mac Catalyst app that features language translation using the Firebase machine learning framework.

I know by default that the frameworks are designed to support iOS. But if I want to built a new Catalyst app (where it's an iOS app that will port over to MacOS), how do I get these frameworks to work?

I just tried to compile for the Mac and I get this error:

```
ld: building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, file '/Documents/TestAppCatalyst/Pods/FirebaseMLNLTranslate/Frameworks/FirebaseMLNLTranslate.framework/FirebaseMLNLTranslate' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It's a bit cryptic but I am guessing it means I am trying to use a framework designed for the iOS but I can't. Has anyone come up with a workaround for this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

ML Kit does not currently support Mac Catalyst.  It only supports iOS at the moment.

Comment: That is a shame, I decided to just build an iPad app that can be run on M1 Macs.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate'` for the same.